# ContactsRequest.Insert(feedUri, newEntry) sometimes fails with System.Net.ProtocolViolationException

Tags: c#, gdata, google-contacts-api

I have this piece of code for adding a contact in a test gmail account I created:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private const string ClientId = "someclientid"
    private const string CliendSecret = "muchsecretwow";

    private const string ApplicationName = "such app";
    private const string RedirectUri = "http://localhost";

    private const string Scopes = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";
    private OAuth2Parameters _parameters;

    private string _accessToken, _refreshToken;
    public void GoogleApiCallAddContact() {
        GetOAuthParameters();
        if (!GetTokensFromMemory())
            throw new Exception("please create new authorization code");
        _parameters.AccessToken = _accessToken;
        _parameters.RefreshToken = _refreshToken;

        var settings = new RequestSettings(ApplicationName, _parameters);


        var cr = new ContactsRequest(settings);

        var newEntry = new Contact {
            Name = new Name {
                FullName = "John Foo",
                GivenName = "John",
                FamilyName = "Foo",
            },
            Content = "some info"
        };

        newEntry.Emails.Add(new EMail {
            Primary = true,
            Rel = ContactsRelationships.IsOther,
            Address = "foo@somemailserver.com"
        });


        var feedUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");


        cr.Insert(feedUri, newEntry);



    }

    private void GetOAuthParameters() {
        _parameters = new OAuth2Parameters {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            ClientSecret = CliendSecret,
            RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
            Scope = Scopes,
        };
    }

    private bool GetTokensFromMemory() {
        if (File.Exists("./tokens.txt")) {
            var lines = File.ReadLines("./tokens.txt").ToList();
            _accessToken = lines[0];
            _refreshToken = lines[1];
            return true;
        }
        _accessToken = _refreshToken = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sometimes(and sometimes not,maybe depending on non-deterministic parameters) I get this exception:

```
System.Net.ProtocolViolationException : When performing a write operation with AllowWriteStreamBuffering set to false, you must either set ContentLength to a non-negative number or set SendChunked to true.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckProtocol(Boolean onRequestStream)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
   at Google.GData.Client.GOAuth2Request.Execute()
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry, AsyncSendData data)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, TEntry entry)
   at Google.GData.Client.FeedRequest`1.Insert(Uri address, Y entry)
   at SomeDirectory.Tests.SomeClass.GoogleApiCallAddContact() in GmailApiLearningTests.cs: line 124
```

Which seems to be out of my code's scope, since it's deep within gdata's implementation. It's also strange that when I get this exception on adding a contact, an other test that uses a ContactRequest to get all contacts works just fine. Any insights on this?

---

**Update:** To anyone having the same issue do this:

```
try{
   cr.Insert(feedUri,newEntry);
}
catch(System.Net.ProtocolViolationException)
{
   cr.Insert(feedUri,newEntry);
}
```

The problem is that the first insert fails(because of the invalid access token), the client lib calls OAuthUtil.RefreshAccessToken(parameters) but somehow fails to re-issue the insert with the new token or at least fail with a GDataRequestException->WebException for unauthorized. So by doing the above, you get your tokens refreshed and manually re-issue the insert call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error and the problem was that the token had expired. You can confirm that using fiddler. I had a 401 error. Once I refreshed the token, everything worked fine. Hope that help.

Comment: It seems you are right. Although it's weird that the access token gets automatically refreshed(like in all requests) but the contactsRequest.Insert throws, instead of using the new ones like GetContacts() or Retrieve does. Thanks again.

Comment: `When performing a write operation with AllowWriteStreamBuffering set to false, you must either set ContentLength to a non-negative number or set SendChunked to true.`
I have faced this error create contact using 
`Contact createdEntry = cr.Insert(request.RequestUri, newEntry)`
this code. Pls help me.