# Insert events to google Apps contact in C#

Tags: c#, google-api, gdata, google-contacts-api

I am trying to add event to Google Apps contacts using Google.GData.Contacts Api in c#.

```
 When objwhen = new When();
 String objwhen1 = (year + "-" + month + "-" + day);

 var nowString = dt.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
 IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
 DateTime dateVal = DateTime.ParseExact(objwhen1, "yyyy-MM-dd", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);

 objwhen.StartTime = dt.ToUniversalTime();
 string str = objwhen.StartTime.ToString();

 newContact.ContactEntry.Events.Add(new Google.GData.Contacts.Event()
                        {

                            Relation = "anniversary",
                            When = objwhen,
                            Label = "Anniversary"
                        });
```

Till here there is no error or exception but when inserting contact

```
createdContact = contactRequest.Insert(feedUri, newContact);
```

It throws exception :
Execution of request failed: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full

Please suggest solutin

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter an error when your token had expired. Once you refreshed the token, everything should work fine. You get your tokens refreshed and manually re-issue the insert call using this snippet:

```
try{
   cr.Insert(feedUri,newContact);
}
catch(System.Net.ProtocolViolationException)
{
   cr.Insert(feedUri,newContact);
}
```

Check this related [SO ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23804960/contactsrequest-insertfeeduri-newentry-sometimes-fails-with-system-net-protoc). Hope this helps!

Comment: If I try to add events to contact then only it throws exception & its not ProtocolViolationException.